# How do i preload scss in next js

Tags: css, next.js

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Head>
          <link rel="preload" href="/styles/globals.scss" as="style" />
          {/* Add other head elements if needed */}
        </Head>
        <SkeletonTheme height={10} baseColor="#66737F" highlightColor="#ADB9C7">
          <CollegeDomain>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />, Component.layout)}</CollegeDomain>
          <ToastContainer />
        </SkeletonTheme>
      </Provider>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} position="bottom-right" />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};
```

here I have tried to preload using link but the css is not getting applies this way

Comment: Browsers do not understand SCSS - SCSS must be transpiled to CSS first. See [SCSS/SASS guide](https://sass-lang.com/guide/) and [nextjs - sass](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/sass). Why are you trying to "preload" the scss file? Just use the .css file resulting from the nextjs transpilation.